# Javascript: Self invoking singleton function vs creating instances of the function?

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

Which one is better to implement in revealing modular pattern in javascript:

1. Having a self invoking function which will get intialized just once at the time JS gets rendered, like this:

```html
<div id="output">
</div>

<script>
   var calculator = function()
{
        add = function(x,y){
           return x+y;
        };        
        return { add:add };
}();

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = calculator.add(5,3);;


</script>
```

---- OR -----

2. Having a constructor to do this like:

```html
<div id="output">
</div>

<script>
  var calculator = function()
  {
        add = function(x,y){
             return x+y;
          };
          return { add:add };
  };
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = new calculator().add(5,3); 
</script>
```

In 1st, benefit I read is that each function will be initialized just once while in 2nd, we will have copies of function for each object initialized.

But the problem in 1st is that it will do some work to make that single copy during the JS load time.

I am confused why would we have multiple copies of function in memory in case2 as memory should be allocated to variables and not functions.

Which of these 2 approach is correct and how to decide which to pick when?

Comment: The first pattern is equivalent of a singleton pattern. If you want to share some resources you use modular pattern to create a single instance and make everyone use that instance. For example a DB connection

Comment: @marvel308: what about memory allocation? How does memory get allocated for these two?

Comment: I would suggest go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management . and read how does new keyword allocate memory and about garbage collection

Answer (score 0):

3) a simple js object? :

```
var calculator = {
  add(a,b){
   return a+b;
  }
};

alert(calculator.add(1,2))
```

As you neither want multiple instances ( which the second approach is good for) and youre not having private variables ( which a closure is good for), the upper is probably the way to go.

Comment: I have oversimplified the situation.. I need to expose only few functions in this object, so return would be needed. I Will edit the question.

Comment: I just want to understand how memory allocation works in 1,2 or 3 so that I can choose these as and when it's needed

Comment: @maverick well 2 is actually not a constructor but a factory.

Comment: @maverick you cant compare them as theyre made for different problems. Comparing them makes no sense